# Do I need multi-threading when running a database server from a python script

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, multithreading

I am using a postgres database for the first time. I am using python 3 in miniconda in Windows 10 and Lubuntu.

I want to start my database server from my python script (on the cron). When it starts, nothing else get executed in my script. Do I need multi-threading or it's something else?

thanks everyone

Comment: Normally, subprocess.run() is used for these purposes.

Comment: Thanks I found this post. It's seems promising: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3

Comment: @AmabDe `run()` [or `call()`] might be what @David is using now as they describe the potential blocking behavior that these methods produce. Perhaps either `Popen()` as it is non-blocking or `run()` but starting postgres in the background: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/server-start.html

Comment: I already tried Popen(). What happens is , from my python script I start my server with Popen('pg_ctl -D path/to/dbCluster start') and then all the rest of my script never get executed because it's running the server. Subprocess seems the way to go in this case.

Comment: I tried subprocess.run() instead of os.popen(). It's a bit different in the behavior, but it works. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried subprocess.run() instead of os.popen() and it works